# Hardhat compilation failed because of Openzepplin library

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

My contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GNU AGPLv3
//https://choosealicense.com/licenses/

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./AmaFansCoreStorage.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@v4.4.2/security/ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@v4.4.2/utils/AddressUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@v4.4.2/access/AccessControlEnumerableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@v4.4.2/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@v4.4.2/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
// import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/CountersUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@4.4.2/utils/CountersUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable@v4.4.2/metatx/ERC2771ContextUpgradeable.sol";

import "./ENS.sol";
import "./AmaFansLib.sol";
import "./AmaFansNFT.sol";
import "./AmaFansCoreEvents.sol";
import "./AmaSessions/IAmaSession.sol";
contract AmaFansCore is AmaFansCoreEvents,
                        Initializable, 
                        PausableUpgradeable,
                        ERC2771ContextUpgradeable,
                        AccessControlEnumerableUpgradeable,
                        ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable,
                        AmaFansCoreStorage{}
```

Everything is getting compiled in remix, but when I am doing `npx hardhat compile', I am getting the following error.

```
Error HH411: The library @openzeppelin/contracts@v4.4.2, imported from contracts/AmaFansCore.sol, is not installed. Try installing it using npm.

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH411 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

I have installed the openzepplin package multiple times but with no success with compilation.

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.2
```